# Does avg_query for PgBouncer include update and inserts?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance

Trying to tune our application and would like to know if the stats data that pgBouncer shows as `avg_query`, according to [the PgBouncer docs on usage](http://pgbouncer.projects.pgfoundry.org/doc/usage.html):

```
avg_query
    Average query duration in microseconds.
```

includes the average duration for `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s as well as `SELECT`s.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - pgbouncer does not know what type a query is, it just passes it through to the backend. Therefor, avg_query is across all queries, including both INSERT, UPDATE and DDL statements.